# When to use wp_reset_postdata();

Tags: loop

I created a child theme for the tweentysixteen theme template.  I see the main loop located in index.php, but noticed that after the while statement, there is no display of `wp_reset_postdata();` If I was to put it there, would the the loop gain any benefit?

For testing purposes I want to display a second loop under the first one, with page limits.  I am assuming it should look like this...

```
$mposts = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3');
    while ( $mposts->have_posts() ) : $mposts->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
```

and if that is correct, do I place a `wp_reset_query`, before this process or after it?  if it is helpful to have it, why does it matter where it is placed?

Thanks!

Comment: This was a legitimate question I was actually writing up an answer for. You shouldn't be using `wp_reset_query()` and instead be using `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: haha - I was scared that this was a stupid question.  my  bad

Comment: If you're trying to learn or understand something stupid questions are extremely rare, this is not one of those :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we should talk about *why* you need to use [`wp_reset_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) in the first place.

What `wp_reset_query()` does is reset the `global $wp_query` object back to it's original state. Since you're creating a **new WP_Query** object / instance, it **does not** overwrite the `global $wp_query` object. The only real case you would need to call this function is if you're using [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) which you shouldn't be in 99% of cases.

Whenever you loop through a custom WP_Query ( using [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) as you have above ) it will overwrite the `global $post` object which means we should be using [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) instead. Since it only happens during The Loop process, we should call the function *after* The Loop. We should be checking to ensure we have posts in the first place and to ensure we don't call this function unnecessarily we would want to put it inside the conditional as seen in the example below:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $myquery->have_posts() ) {

    while( $myquery->have_posts() ) {
        $myquery->the_post();
        /** Content **/
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the definition and demo.  Howdy, if this example was the second loop on the page, would you also place a rewind_posts() above this second loop?  would that be beneficial?

Comment: nevermind - i think i found my answer to this side question here - https://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/ its nice to see there are multiple ways to handling this!

Comment: @blackhawk I believe if you need to run the custom loop ( seen above ) twice, you would need to put `$myquery->rewind_posts()` either at the end ( but inside ) of the first conditional or above the second conditional. If you don't rewind the posts before it hits the second conditional, `have_posts()` will probably fail.